# Cannot add foreign key constraint, driving me crazy, please help:)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE country
(
country_id VARCHAR (20),
country_name CHAR (20),
state_no INT (5),
PRIMARY KEY (country_id));

CREATE TABLE cities
(
city_name VARCHAR (20),
country_name CHAR (20),
country_id VARCHAR (20),
PRIMARY KEY (city_name),
FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country);
```

These are two tables I have created, the first one is executing fine but I get the 1215 error about being unable to add the foreign key constraint. I'm really not sure why and have been pulling my hair out for nearly an hour. I'm sure it really simple and I'm being stupid.

Comment: Thanks for editing that btw, looked terrible before.

Comment: Highlight code blocks and click the `{}` editor toolbar button, or `ctl-k`. 4-space indentation, plus a blank line before makes a code block.

Comment: Thank you, will do in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country);
```

Because your `Country` and `country_id` are of different data-type.
I hope you are referencing to `country_id`  than `country`

```
FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country_id);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify the column you want to reference.

```
FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country(country_id));
```

Comment: I was in the process of writing a longer answer, so here's the demonstraion: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d71a2